# Swift : Dynamic set 3 UILabel width after each button

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic, tableview, height

[image: Custom table view cell with radiou butotn options]

Above is the screenshot of what I have done so far. Progmatically I created radio buttons and labels respective to it in cellForRowAtIndex method. I have one issue, the label width is static. But I want to make dynamic width.

If I run this in iPhone 6 then it works fine but if I run this in iPhone 5 then last label will cross the view.

So please any suggestion is helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Making the label width to be dynamic is kind of unclear of your case, should the three sections be equals width? what if on of the label width is too long, should it push the other sections?

Comment: It means I can't make  dynamically width

Comment: If I run this in iPhone 6 then it works fine but if I run this in iPhone 5 then last label will cross the view....

Comment: So in iPhone 5, what is the expected result? should it contains a truncating at the end "..."?

Comment: no last label cross the view and only some text is visible